# Why doesn't windbg command !heap show all process heaps?

Tags: windbg

I create a new heap using HeapCreate function, then check that that heap is returned from GetProcessHeaps (it is ok), but the windbg command !heap does not show new created heap. Moreover, !heap shows twice less than function GetProcessHeaps. Why is it happening and how to display all heaps by WinDbg?

Comment: Ok, i've found answer. That behavior is when app verifier is enabled.